# How to redirect sub.domain.com to proper url

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, subdomain, asp.net-webpages

I have a website and some sub-domains which are working like so:

http://sub.domain.com/ goes to: http://www.domain.com/sub/.

But what I *want* it do do is:

http://sub.domain.com/ goes to: http://sub.domain.com/sub/ but still keep the URI in the address bar the same, so it should read: http://sub.domain.com/.

So when a user enters http://sub.domain.com/ in the address bar, it will display content from http://sub.domain.com/sub/ but still display http://sub.domain.com/ in the address bar.

If the user visits another page in sub.domain.com website the address bar should still display correct address which might be something like http://sub.domain.com/page2.html instead of http://domain.com/sub/page2.html.

How can we achieve this? I've done it years ago but to be honest I don't remember the approach I used and I have tried a few articles online but they weren't correct.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you

My current code is:

```
@{
    // Redirect from subdomain if necessary.
    string variables = (Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]);

    switch(variables.Trim().ToLower())
    {
        case "sub.domain.com":
            Response.Redirect("http://domain.com/sub/", true);
            break;
        default:
            Layout = "~/Shared/_View.cshtml";
            break;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can't you just change Response.Redirect("http://domain.com/sub/", true); to Response.Redirect("/sub/", true); ?

Comment: 404 Not Found. And not sure why, either.

Comment: Does your URL http://sub.domain.com/sub/ actually work for you?